# Expected number of same numbered balls in a box

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

I have two boxes: A,B. The boxes A contains $n_1$ red balls which numbered from $(1, \cdots, n_1)$. The box B includes $n_2$ green balls which also numbered from $(1, \cdots, n_2)$.

Throw balls from two boxes into a box C. However, some balls will drop-out with probability is $p$. **How many balls have the same number in box C?**
A toy example is shown in below figure. In which, the box C will contain two balls (4,7) are the same number. Thus, the answer is 2.

[image]

Comment: "How many balls have the same number.." is a bit vague. Don't you mean: Of how many numbers can be said that it is doubly represented in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m:=\min(n_1,n_2)$ and for $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ let $X_i$ take value $1$ if a red and a blue ball both with number $i$ will end up in box $C$. If this does not happen then let $X_i$ take value $0$. Then $$X:=X_1+\dots+X_m$$ equals the number of numbers doubly presented in box $C$. There are $2X$ balls that have a "numbermate" in the sense that there is another ball in box $C$ having the same number.

If you are after expectation then you can use linearity of expectation and symmetry to find that: $$\mathbb EX=m\Pr(X_1=1)$$

Also the $X_i$ are independent so that $X$ will have binomial distribution with parameters $m$ and $\Pr(X_1=1)$.

Can you find $\Pr(X_1=1)$ yourself?

Comment: Sorry, I still not fully understand your answer. So I cannot compute $Pr(X_1=1)$Could you show a final answer for my question?

Comment: $p$ is just loss probability. Due to loss prob., we will receive $(1-p)n_1+(1-p)n_2$ balls in the box C.

Comment: $X_1=1$ is the event that the red ball with number $1$ and the green ball with number $1$ both did not drop out. Can you find the probability of that event as an expression in $p$?

Comment: Good suggestion. I am thinking it

Comment: The prob. receives number $1$ of red ball is $\frac{1}{n_1}$. With same manner, the prob. receives number $1$ of green ball is $\frac{1}{n_2}$. The prob. receives  with number 1 is $\frac{1}{n_1} \cdot \frac{1}{n_2}$. Is it right?

Comment: I understood out of your question that *every* ball has a chance of $p$ to drop out. Did you mean something else? If not then there is a chance of $(1-p)^2$ that the red and green ball carrying number $1$ did not drop out.

Comment: In my concept, $p$ is loss (drop-out ) probability when we throw these balls from each box to box C. For example, $p=0.1, n_1=10,n_2=20$. Then expected number of ball received at the box C is $9$ red balls and $18$ green balls. From the concept, can we said that every ball has a chance of $p$ to drop out. I think no

Comment: If every ball has a chance of $0.1$ to drop out and $10$ balls are thrown then the expectation of the number of balls that are received is indeed $9$. As you said earlyer $(1-p)n_1+(1-p)n_2$ can be expected to be received in total. That fully agrees with: *every* ball has a chance of $p$ tot drop out.

Comment: Thank you. So, the final answer will be $\min(n1,n2) \times (1-p)^2$ is expected number of couples having same number. Is it right?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just want to ask an extension version of the question. What is happen if numbered balls of box B is randomly number and up to $n_2$ ($n_2<n_1$) (random but must be unique), instead of from $(1,\cdots, n_2)$ as original question?

Comment: It goes too far to treat that with a comment. We have gone too far with that allready. I must advice you to ask this in a new question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your ans. I posted a new question about that in link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842299/expected-number-of-couples-having-same-number