# Compute expected received balls from boxes

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have 6 boxes: $A,B,A',B',C \text{ and } D$. The box $A$ has $n_1$ red balls that are numbered from $1, \cdots, n_1$. The box $B$ has $n_2$ green balls that are numbered from $1, \cdots, n_2$. Make a copy version of these boxes $A,B$  are $A',B'$ (It means the box $A'$ has $n_1$ red balls from $1, \cdots, n_1$, and the box $B'$ has $n_2$ green balls from $1, \cdots, n_2$ ). These two boxes $C,D$ have no balls. Let $p$ be loss probability when we throw balls from a box to another box (each ball gets dropped with independent probability $p$). (For example, if we throw a ball from the box $A$ to box $C$ with loss prob. is $p=10\%$, then $90\%$ the ball will not drop. Then expected number of received ball in box $C$ will be $0.9n_1$ balls...).

First, I will throw these balls from $A$ and $B$ to the box $C$ with loss probability is $p$. Call number of red and green balls in box $C$ are $n_{1C},n_{2C}$, respectively. Then, randomly select $r$ balls from the box $C$, with $0 \le r \le \min(n_1,n_2,n_{1C}+n_{2C})$. Throw these $r$ balls to the box $D$ with loss probability $p$.

Second, throw these balls from these boxes $A',B'$ to the box $D$ with loss probability $p$.

How many (expected number) red balls do we have in the box $D$ in term of $p$, if two red balls have the same number (i.e number 4 of a red ball from $A' \to D$, and number 4 of a red ball from $C \to D$), then the red ball only counts 1 time? In the same manner, how many green balls do we have in the box $D$? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: This question is very  hard to read...there's a lot of unhelpful verbiage, the variable names are confusing and the picture doesn't add anything.  I think, but am not at all sure, that you are asking this:  "you have a bunch of balls, red ones $r_i$ and green ones $g_i$.  Each specific ball, like $r_1$, say, has two independent ways of making it to box $D$.  Either it goes there directly (probability $q=1-p$) or it goes there after making a stop (probability $q^2$) or it could reach by both routes (probability q^3).  What's the expected number that makes it to box $D$?  Do I have it right?

Comment: Note:  if I have understood the question correctly (a big if) then it isn't difficult, and I'll write up a solution.  If I have misunderstood, perhaps you could clarify?  To stress:  I am not at all sure I am reading it correctly.  For example, I don't think the "red and green" have anything to do with it.  There are just $n_1+n_2$ balls.  Could be different colors, could be the same.

Comment: Thank lulu. My question is extended version of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842299/expected-number-of-couples-having-same-number

Comment: Is my interpretation correct?  If so then, barring blunder, my posted solution ought to be correct.  If my interpretation is not correct, could you clarify the way in which I have misunderstood it?

Comment: Sorry, I am reading your solution. Wait for me few min.

Comment: Let briefly explain my target. I have two boxes with red and green balls which are numbered to classify a unified ball. First, I throw these balls to a box $C$. Second, with same balls as box $A,B$ before throwing the box C. I will these balls + balls in box C to box D, satisfy the above condition. My goal is to compute how many red ball has unique number

Comment: You phrase things in a very confusing way.  Now the balls are red and blue instead of red and green?  Let's stick to my phrasing.  Is my phrasing correct?  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: sorry I was missing about blue and green

Comment: What do the colors have to do with anything?  You just have $n_1+n_2$ balls.  Each ball has two ways to reach the goal.  Keep it simple.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41869/discussion-between-user3051460-and-lulu).

Comment: Not interested in chatting, sorry.  I hope my solution helps. As far as I can see, it should answer your question.  Maybe you want the red and green balls to have different "drop probabilities"?  that would explain the two colors.  Easy to modify my solution to cover that case.

Comment: I must color it because when I throw them to box D. I want to count how many balls have same color but unique number

Comment: Well, I don't get it but fine.  Isn't that what I compute below?  $E[Red]$ is the number of unique indices seen amongst the red balls in $D$.  Similarly, $E[Green]$ is the number of unique indices seen amongst the green ones.  Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I believe I answered exactly that question.  What condition did I not use?

Comment: The condition is  "Then, randomly select $r$ balls from the box $C$, with $0 \le r \le \min(n_1,n_2,n_{1C}+n_{2C})$". I guarantee that sending packets between link $C \to D$ is not greater than $\min(n_1,n_2)$, when loss prob. is low

Comment: Oh, Ok. Yes, I missed that one.  Not so easy to add that one in...let me think for a minute.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be easy to incorporate that filter.  The problem is that for fixed $r$ the probability that a given ball in $C$ is tossed towards $D$ depends on $\frac 1{n_{1,C}+n_{2,C}}$.  We therefore need to compute $E\left[\frac 1{n_{1,C}+n_{2,C}}\right]$. But there aren't nice expressions for the reciprocal of a binomial distribution...there are some formulas involving Beta functions, but nothing terribly clean.  Maybe I am missing something, but that filter seems hard to work with analytically.  Easy to simulate, of course.

Comment: Yes, it is easy to implement but difficult to model. I think that the number of balls at C is $R=q(n1+n2)$, then we select $r$ ball from these balls, we have $\binom{R}{r}$ possible case. For each case, we send the balls to D.

Comment: No.  That's the problem.  the number of balls in $C$ is a random variable.  True, the expected value is $q\times (n_1+n_2)$ but that doesn't help as much as you think.  Remember that $E\left[\frac 1X\right]\neq \frac 1{E[X]}$.

Comment: Yes, If we have no filter at C. You are right that number of unique red ball at D will be $(q+q^2-q^3)n_1$, but instead of chosing all balls in C and throw to D. I just randomly select $r$ balls and throw them to D. It is very hard to me

Comment: I'd stick with the simulation.  Like I said, it's perfectly possible that I am missing some simplification here.  As a rule, though, I'd simulate things like reciprocals of binomial distributions.  Sorry, but that's the best I can think of for now.

Comment: Thank luu. As my simulation, the result shows a linearity line in term of $p$. Hope it give you some ideal

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:  as the OP points out in the comments, this solution incorrectly assumes that ALL balls in $C$ are subsequently tossed over towards $D$.  That case may still be relevant so I will leave this up for now and will modify it if I can incorporate the filter from $C$.

Let $X_i$ denote the indicator variable for the $i^{th}$ red ball.  Thus $X_i=1$ if $r_i$ eventually gets to box $D$ (either once or twice) and $X_i=0$ otherwise.  Let $E[Red]$ be the expected number of red balls that eventually make it to $D$.  Then by linearity of expectation $$E[Red]=E\left[\sum X_i\right]=\sum E[X_i]=\phi\times n_1$$  Where $\phi$ denotes the probability that a given red ball makes it (either once or twice).  It's easy to compute $\phi$.  The chosen ball makes it along the path $A'\to D$ with probability $q=1-p$ and it makes it there along the path $A\to C \to D$ with probability $q^2$.  Adding these double counts those cases in which the ball makes it via both routes, which happens with probability $q^3$.  Thus $$\phi=q+q^2-q^3\implies E[Red]=(q+q^2-q^3)\times n_1$$

The same argument shows that $E[Green]=(q+q^2-q^3)\times n_2$  and the final answer is just $$E=E[Red]+E[Green]=(q+q^2-q^3)\times (n_1+n_2)$$